# wrap all elements after each specific tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to wrap all `div`s after each `h4` tag so then i can modify the column size depending on the results.

As is:

```
<div class="bannerPrincipales">
  <h4 class="col-md-12 hotels-area punta-cana">Punta Cana</h4>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
  <h4 class="col-md-12 hotels-area bayahibe">Bayahibe</h4>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
  <h4 class="col-md-12 hotels-area riviera-maya">Riviera Maya</h4>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
</div>
```

To be:

```
<div class="bannerPrincipales">
  <h4 class="col-md-12 hotels-area punta-cana">Punta Cana</h4>
  <div class="description-wrap">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
  </div>
  <h4 class="col-md-12 hotels-area bayahibe">Bayahibe</h4>
  <div class="description-wrap">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
  </div>
  <h4 class="col-md-12 hotels-area riviera-maya">Riviera Maya</h4>
  <div class="description-wrap">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I tried:

```
$(" h4.hotels-area").each(function(){
  $(this).nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="description-wrap"></div>')
});
```

When I do this it messed up my HTML. I do not have access to the html so i need to do it this way, once i wrap then i will count how many div are into the `description-wrap` class, but I can't get to wrap.

I thought on wrapping because what i need is to be able to count how many col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left are after each h4 and if the result is an unpaired number the first col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left i will change the cols to col-md-12 without knowing how col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left i have after each h4 i won't be able to achive my goal

Comment: wrapping those divs is not a good approach to solving this problem, because the wrapper divs will destroy the grid layout set up by your class `col-` styles, because they are no longer siblings and the sizes will be broken

Comment: You might describe your goal a little better. There may be a more elegant solution available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `div.description-wrap` after each `h4` tag inside `.bannerPrincipales` (with the [`jQuery.after`](https://api.jquery.com/after/) function).
Then, you could cycle each `div` inside `.bannerPrincipales`, and say:

- if it has `description-wrap` class, then it will be the `wrapper`;
- else append it inside `wrapper` (with the [`jQuery.append`](https://api.jquery.com/after/) function).

And, finally, you could count the number of `div`s inside `wrapper` with the `length` property.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.bannerPrincipales h4').after('<div class="description-wrap"></div>');
  let wrapper = null;
  $('.bannerPrincipales div').each((i, div) => {
    if ($(div).hasClass('description-wrap')) {
      wrapper = div;
    } else {
      $(wrapper).append(div);
    }
  });
  $('.bannerPrincipales .description-wrap').each((i, wrapper) => {
    let place = $('.bannerPrincipales h4:eq(' + i + ')').text();
    let n = $(wrapper).find('div').length;
    console.log(place + ' has ' + n + ' divs');
  });
});
```

```css
.description-wrap {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bannerPrincipales">
  <h4 class="col-md-12 hotels-area punta-cana">Punta Cana</h4>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left">b</div>
  <h4 class="col-md-12 hotels-area bayahibe">Bayahibe</h4>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left">c</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left">d</div>
  <h4 class="col-md-12 hotels-area riviera-maya">Riviera Maya</h4>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left">e</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left">f</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left">g</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is adding the class to each div after the h4, but how will count how many col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-banner-left are after each h4.. example first 4h has 2, sencond  h4 has 3 amd so on

Comment: @walteralexander I have updated the answer with your new request